# Get array of raw pointers from array of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, smart-pointers

I have a library function that requires an array of four pointers as parameter: `f(unsigned char* data[4])`, and I have an array of smart pointers in my code: `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char> myArray[4]`.

Is there a way to use the smart pointers with this library function ?

I have already tried this but it gives me a segfault: `f(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char **>(myArray[0].get()));`

Comment: Copy the pointers to an array of four pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::array<unsigned char* , 4> arr = { myArray[0].get(),myArray[1].get(),myArray[2].get(),myArray[3].get() };
```

pass `arr.data()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your cast is wrong. You are casting the `unsigned char *` pointer that is stored in the 1st array element. You would need to cast the address of the element itself:

```
f(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char **>(&myArray[0]));
```

Or even cast the array itself:

```
using puchar = unsigned char *;
f(reinterpret_cast<puchar(&)[4]>(myArray));
```

However, these only work because `std::unique_ptr` is designed to have no more storage overhead than a raw pointer.  But it is undefined behavior to use these solutions.  The correct solution is to simply copy the pointers to another array, eg:

```
unsigned char* myArrayOfPtrs[] = { myArray[0].get(), myArray[1].get(), myArray[2].get(), myArray[3].get() };
f(myArrayOfPtrs);
```

Or:

```
unsigned char* myArrayOfPtrs[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    myArrayOfPtrs[i] = myArray[i].get();
}
f(myArrayOfPtrs);
```

Or:

```
#include <algorithm>

unsigned char* myArrayOfPtrs[4];
std::transform(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), std::begin(myArrayOfPtrs),
    [](auto &p) { return p.get(); }
);
f(myArrayOfPtrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your `unique_ptr` will not be out of scope and want it to retain ownership of the associated pointers you can use `char* a[] = {myArray[0].get(), myArray[1].get(), myArray[2].get(), myArray[3].get()}` on each pointer in the array and create an array of regular pointers.

The `unique_pointers` retain ownership of the `char*` resource and if they go out of scope the `unique_ptr` destructor will free the pointers.

If you want to release ownership you can use the `release()` method on the `unique_ptr`s and this will allow you to safely convert to a regular pointer and ensure that the `unique_ptr` going out of scope will not deallocate the underlying char* resource.

`release()`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release

`get()`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get